# Custom close reason needs an update

Tags: discussion, bug, feature-request, status-completed

One of the off topic close reasons contains a link to come talk about it in chat

> Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat.

However, the link to chat goes to the now defunct Mos Eisley.